# Changing images in imgarrays using individual buttons

Tags: javascript, html

So I made a dropdown menu of buttons, with submenus within it and I want each button within that to change a single image to a different image(each button with it's own image except the dropdown category buttons) I'm thinking with an imagearray so I don't have to have so many functions. This is my code for the button dropdown.I realized its not styled. Also I don't want the picture to take place of the menu or button but to be separately located.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.dropbtn {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    color: black;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}


    .dropbtn2 {
    background-color:#f9f9f9;
    color: black;
    padding: 8px;
    font-size: 16px;
    min-width: 160px;
    border-style: outset;
    cursor: pointer;
}



.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.dropdown {
    position:relative;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-choices {
    display: none;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    overflow:auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;

    }



.show {display:block;}



</style>
</head>
<body>



<div class="dropdown">
<button id='btn0'class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <button id='home' class="dropbtn2">Home</button><br/>
      <div id="myDropdown2" class="dropdown-choices">
        <button value="0"selected>Pencil</button><br/>
        <button value="1">Eraser</button><br/>
        <button value="2">Ruler</button><br/>
      </div>
    <button id='school' class="dropbtn2">School</button><br/>
      <div id="myDropdown3" class="dropdown-choices">
        <button value="3">Football</button><br/>
        <button value="4">baseball</button><br/>
      </div>

  </div>
</div> 


<script type="text/javascript">


document.getElementById("btn0").addEventListener("click", function(){   
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
});
document.getElementById("home").addEventListener("click", function(){    
  document.getElementById("myDropdown2").classList.toggle("show");
});
document.getElementById("school").addEventListener("click", function(){    
  document.getElementById("myDropdown3").classList.toggle("show");
});


</script>

<script type="text/javascript">





    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And this is a changeimage() function i got to work with a version of my code thats using a select menu rather than buttons. It worked perfect but i can't get it to work with buttons, any idea how to get it work or to get something similar to work. Sorry I've self teaching myself so my code might be strange. Thank  you for any help and/or tips.

```
 <body>

  <select id="choose_img" onchange="changeImage()" class="OptionMenu1">
    <optgroup label="Common Office Supplies"\>
    <option value="0" selected>Pencil</option>
    <option value="1">Eraser</option>
    <option value="2">Ruler</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Common Sports Balls">
    <option value="3">American Football</option>
    <option value="4">Baseball</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
  <br/>
  <img id="image" class="Image1"/>


<script type="text/javascript">    

var imgArray = [
"pic_pencil",
"pic_eraser",
"pic_ruler",
"pic_football",
"pic_baseball"
];

var selectImg = document.getElementById("choose_img");
var imgElement = document.getElementById("image");

function changeImage()
{
  var index = selectImg.value;
  imgElement.src = imgArray[index];
}

// select the first image
changeImage(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I undertstood your problem, you can simply call your ChangeImage function on button click.

```
<button onclick="changeImage(3)">Football</button>
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: '<button value="0"onclick="changeImage(0)"selected>Pencil</button><br/>
        <button value="1"onclick="changeImage(1)">Eraser</button><br/>
        <button value="2"onclick="changeImage(2)">Ruler</button><br/>            Like that? I'm trying that but the images still dont show up

Comment: Can you please provide a jsfiddle ?